# Java CMS and Parallel GC with multiple gc threads, what each thread does

Tags: jvm

Is it a master slave implementation or each GC thread does specific tasks. If it is a master(controller)  slave(workers) implementation, how does it select the master?. Is the implementation different for concurrent and parallel mode.

Comment: GCs are implementation details and change over time. They also consist of multiple phases, where phases could be implemented differently. *If* it uses a master/slave architecture then there will be no need to "decide", the master would be the first thread that start/manage the others.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is there in Openjdk-9. Or can you give some guidance on where i can i find details about this (book or online docs).

Comment: The best details are in the source. As these details change between releases it would become quickly out of date. Also it is not a good idea to be too tied to how a specific version is implemented.